# JQM Toolbar (Header and Footer) moving with scrolling Windows phone 8

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, cordova-3

I am using Cordova with JQuery mobile, it working fine on android, but when made build for Windows Phone 8, the JQM Toolbar(Header and footer) not getting fix, Toolbar little goes up when I am scrolling up page and when I am scrolling down the toolbar little goes down, like below screenshots
http://159.100.223.157/screens/IMG_0712.JPG
http://159.100.223.157/screens/IMG_0713.JPG
here is the code

```
<div role="main">
<div id="SearchRides" data-role="page" class="page innerPage">
<div class="ui-header ui-bar-a ui-header-fixed header" data-position="fixed">
<a href="search-result.html" class="ui-btn-right icon-ok" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
<h1 aria-level="1" role="heading" class="ui-title">Search</h1>
</div>
<!--end header-->
<div class="projects ui-content content">
<form method="post" action="#">
<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="txtFrom" style="text-align: center">Source</label>
<input type="text" name="txtFrom" id="txtFrom" placeholder="To">
</div>
</form>
</div>
<!--end body-->
<div data-theme="a" class="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" rel="external" class="icon-home-footer" data-iconpos="notext">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
 <!--end footer-->
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your images are blank as well.